# Cron job doesn't work, but runs successfully manually

Tags: raspbian, cron

I have directories in my home folder that hold reports uploaded via FTP. The daily folders are named like YYYYMMDD. At 00:01, I want to delete the folder from four days ago. At 01:01, I want to change the access to 755 on the previous day's folder.

The statements work when entered on the command-line, but not from root's cron. I tried using `find`, but I got the same behavior. The single line python statement is preferable because I don't need to scan the entire folder; this is on a model b, so using `find` is slow, and unnecessary since I know exactly what I want to work with.

```
rm -rf /home/me/reports/`/usr/bin/python -c 'import datetime; print (datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(days=-4)).strftime("%Y%m%d")'`
chmod -R 755 /home/me/reports/`python -c 'import datetime; print (datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(days=-1)).strftime("%Y%m%d")'`
```

These are the lines from root's crontab:

```
1 0 * * *     rm -rf /home/me/reports/`/usr/bin/python -c 'import datetime; print (datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(days=-4)).strftime("%Y%m%d")'`
1 1 * * *     chmod -R 700 /home/me/reports/`/usr/bin/python -c 'import datetime; print (datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(days=-1)).strftime("%Y%m%d")'`
```

Comment: Does your crontab file has an empty line at the end? (You want it to. Each line in the crontab needs to end with a _newline_. So there should always be an empty line at the end.) if it does and it still won't run, what's the result of running **sudo crontab -l | grep -v '#'**)

Comment: Yeah it ends with a newline. The lines I posted above are the output of `sudo crontab -l | egrep -v '^#'`

Comment: You seem to have a typo in either `chmod 755` or `chmod 700`. Also, since you're using `chmod -R`, you're marking all your reports as executable scripts. Perhaps you want `chmod -R go-rw` (revoke group's and others' read and write permissions for the directory and everything in it) instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron may not support backtick command expansion. put your commands in a script and run that from cron instead. much easier to debug.

Comment: Yeah I didn't get back ticks to work. I put everything in a script and it worked fine. I was just curious about why it didn't work as I had it.

Comment: @user38537 The backticks probably weren't a problem; the `%` signs definitely were. Of course, moving the commands out of the crontab and into a script removes the special meaning of `%` and thereby fixes your problem.

Comment: @hildred I just got around to actually testing this: The `cron` on my Raspberry (version 3.0pl1-124 from the default Raspbian image) supports both backticks and `$()`.

Answer (score 3):

`%` signs have a special meaning in crontabs and need to be escaped as `\%` -- here's the relevant part from `man 5 crontab`:

> Percent-signs (%)  in  the  command,  unless escaped  with  backslash  (\), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the  command  as standard input.

---

Also note that the [`$(…)` notation should be preferred over backticks](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/126928/28235).

And depending on the version of `date` installed on your system, you might also be able to get rid of the Python script and just use `date -d "now - 4 days" +%Y%m%d` (again escaping the `%` signs for the crontab, of course).